# Can't find Delphi 2007 WSDL Importer

Tags: delphi, delphi-2007

I'm may be missing something but I can't find the Delphi 2007 WSDL Importer anywhere. I've looked in New -> Other -> Web Services where it is supposed to be and all of the other sections as well (just in case) but it's not there. Does the WSDL Importer only ship with some versions of the IDE and not others? Has it been hidden somewhere? When will someone write a Delphi manual that is actually usable?! ;)

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You **Should First** create a new VCL project, and then go to

File | New | Other | Delphi Projects | WebServices | WSDL Importer

Comment: Thanks Cesar. I'll try this tomorrow when I get into work and let you know how I got on.

Comment: Thanks again Cesar. Worked a treat.

Answer (score 1):

I thought it depended on the version of Delphi that you use, I think the Web Services part are only available for entreprises editions ..

You could look  for the WSDL importer that is on the CodeGear site [here](http://cc.codegear.com/Item/24535)

Comment: Thanks Che. I think that this is just the D2007 WSDL Importer for those with earlier versions of Delphi. However, if I can't get to the WSDL Importer in the method described above, I'll give it a shot!